# How to paste dummy text from 1 site to my own using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

When I'm pasting dummy text from any website to my textarea it is not saving into MySQL server but sometimes it works correctly. I don't know why it is happening.

Here is my code:

```
   <table align="center" border="10">
<form method="post" action="insert.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr>
        <td>News Title</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="title" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select Category</td>
        <td>
        <select name="cat">
            <option>Select Your category</option>
            <?php
            include('db.php');
                $query="select * from nav";
                $run=mysql_query($query);
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run)){
                    $m_id=$row[0];
                    $m_title=$row['m_title'];
                    echo "<option value='$m_id'>$m_title</option>";
                    }
            ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>News Image</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="news_image" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>News Description</td>
        <td><textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="desc"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="btn" value="Insert News"/>                </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
</table>`

<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
    $news_title=$_POST['title'];
    $news_cat=$_POST['cat'];
    $news_desc=$_POST['desc'];
    $news_image=$_FILES['news_image']['name'];
    $tmp_image=$_FILES['news_image']['tmp_name'];
    if($news_title=='' || $news_cat=='' || $news_desc==''){
        echo "<script>alert('Any of your field is Empty')</script>";
        exit();
        }

    else{
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_image,"../images/$news_image");
        $insert_query="insert into pages(cat_id,page_title,news_image,page_desc) VALUES ('$news_cat','$news_title','$news_image','$news_desc')";
        $insert_run=mysql_query($insert_query);
        echo "<script>alert('News Inserted...!!!')</script>";
        }
    }
?>`
```

Comment: please provide the error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the input data in case it contains quote characters.

```
$news_title=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
$news_cat=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat']);
$news_desc=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);
$news_image=mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['news_image']['name']);
```

It would be better if you switched form the deprecated mysql extension to PDO or mysqli, and used prepared statements.